# What does this lambda mean? (Python, Numpy, Rotation Matrix, Robotics)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rotation, robotics

In my class, we are learning how to use Python to code robot poses. Specifically, creating a rotation matrix and translation matrix with numpy to represent these relative poses.

The one thing I don't understand is how our lab assistant demonstrated how to create the rotation matrix. I was able to create it a similar way on my own but I'd like to understand what he did. Here is the example he provided:

```
Rot = lambda theta: [[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],
                     [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]]

R = Rot(np.pi/3)
R
```

**Can someone explain what is the `Rot = lambda theta:`  code means?** When I did it on my own I just created a variable `theta` and the equation for `Rot` with the variable `theta` inside of it in the appropriate places. I do not understand what this `lambda` means.

Comment: It returns the rotation matrix for a rotation of theta.

Comment: that is shorthand for `def CreateRotationMatrix(radians): return [[np.cos(radians), -np.sin(radians)].[np.sin(radians), np.cos(radians)]])`

Answer (score 3):

It's the equivalent of this:

```
def Rot(theta):
    return [[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],
            [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]]
```

The code `lambda param1, param2: return_value` creates a function with `param1` and `param2` as parameters, the code after the colon (`:`) is automatically run and returned when you call the function. `Rot =`  is simply assigning the resulting lambda function to the `Rot` variable, and since all functions are actually variables, that works.